# Broken Image in Customer Service (Napili) Community - Spring '17

Tags: napili, images, lightning-community

I've been building our org's Intranet using Communities, and since the update I noticed that if I try to upload any images to include in a rich text editor they appear to be broken and won't display. I've gone between the Community Builder, Preview, and the Published view, but the images I'm trying to display only appear as the broken image icon.
 [image] 
I get the following error message when attempting to load the resources:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503
>   (Service Unavailable)

Anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you try opening your browser console and listing out the errors that are shown? Here is some help on opening it in Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)'

Comment: check if locker service is enabled under setup>critical updates>lockers service. Disable it and check if you still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a "know issue" as described [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001BrFQAU) .

> Summary When LockerService is enabled for sandbox and DE orgs,
>   rich-text editors are disabled and rich-text fields are read-only.

The current workaround is to disable locker service:

Check under setup>critical updates> lockers service. Disable it and validate that the issue is no longer present.

A note from the [developer blogs](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/04/introducing-lockerservice-lightning-components.html) in regards to locker service and rich text fields:

> Note:
>
> When LockerService is activated in sandbox or Developer Edition orgs,
>   you can’t edit rich-text fields and the fields are grayed out. We’re
>   working on removing that limitation in a future release.
>
> IE11 doesn’t
>   support CSP, so we recommend using other supported browsers for
>   enhanced security.